# How can I use npm in wix website editor?

Tags: javascript, npm, twilio, npm-install, velo

I need to install twilio at Wix website editor but I can't find any console or npm there. Does anybody know how can I install it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fetch API](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html) to send a request to any REST API they expose. It is not possible to use npm install inside Wix Code.

Another option is to set up your own server and make the request to it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to have been a change in recent years, and Wix now [supports using npm packages](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-accessing-third-party-services-with-the-fetch-api) as part of their Corvid Dev Mode.

It is possible to use the functionality in the backend web module and then include it from you page: you can find more information in their [documentation](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-managing-external-code-libraries-with-the-package-manager)

[image: Installing NPM packages in Wix projects]